# Need to combine common result of two select statements

Tags: sql

i have to select the common coloumns c1 ,c2,c3  from result of two sql satements.

1)

```
select c1, c2, c3,count(c3)  from (select * from form_name
where data_created >'1273446000' and data_creazione<'1274569200')
group by c1,c2, c3 having count(c3)>1
```

2)

```
select c1, c2, c3,count(c3)  from (select * from form_name 
where data_created>'1272236400' and data_creazione<'1274569200')
group by c1,c2, c3 having count(c3)>2
```

I need to select c1,c2,c3 all same and common found in both the result of query.

how could this be done...could anyone help please?

Comment: You could use UNION to combine the two queries to one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove the `count(c3)` from the select list, it can differ (the HAVING clause guarantees this) and the OP only wants to compare c1, c2 and c3.  If the `COUNT(c3)` column is different, what rows can be in common? none or some, it will vary. Also remove the derived tables, they are not necessary.  So try:

```
select 
    c1, c2, c3  
    from form_name
    where data_created >'1273446000' and data_creazione<'1274569200'
    group by c1,c2, c3 
    having count(c3)>1
INTERSECT
select 
    c1, c2, c3
    from form_name 
    where data_created>'1272236400' and data_creazione<'1274569200'
    group by c1,c2, c3 
    having count(c3)>2
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `INTERSECT` will solve your problem. More Infos [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/intersect.php).

```
select c1, c2, c3,count(c3)  from (select * from form_name
where data_created >'1273446000' and data_creazione<'1274569200')
group by c1,c2, c3 having count(c3)>1    
INTERSECT
select c1, c2, c3,count(c3)  from (select * from form_name 
where data_created>'1272236400' and data_creazione<'1274569200')
group by c1,c2, c3 having count(c3)>2
```

Comment: INTERSECT gives common rows, but this query will not work, see my answer for why.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried joining the 2 queries with 'UNION'?

eg.

```
select c1, c2, c3,count(c3)  from (select * from form_name
where data_created >'1273446000' and data_creazione<'1274569200')
group by c1,c2, c3 having count(c3)>1    
union    
select c1, c2, c3,count(c3)  from (select * from form_name 
where data_created>'1272236400' and data_creazione<'1274569200')
group by c1,c2, c3 having count(c3)>2
```

Comment: UNION gives all rows, OP only wants the common rows

Answer (score 1):

You could use derived tables and then join them together to get the results you want.

```
select a.c1, a.c2, a.c3, a.acount, b.bcount
From 
(select c1, c2, c3, count(*) as acount  from (select * from form_name 
where data_created >'1273446000' and data_creazione<'1274569200') 
group by c1,c2, c3 having count(c3)>1) a
join 
(select c1, c2, c3, count(*) as bcount from (select * from form_name  
where data_created>'1272236400' and data_creazione<'1274569200') 
group by c1,c2, c3 having count(c3)>2)b 
    on a.c1 = b.c1 and a.c2 = b.c2 and a.c3 = b.c3
```